# assign values to list of variables in python

Tags: python

I have made a small demo of a more complex problem

```
def f(a):
    return tuple([x for x in range(a)])

d = {}
[d['1'],d['2']] = f(2)
print d
# {'1': 0, '2': 1} 
# Works
```

Now suppose the keys are programmatically generated
How do i achieve the same thing for this case?

```
n = 10
l = [x for x in range(n)]
[d[x] for x in l] = f(n)
print d
# SyntaxError: can't assign to list comprehension
```

Comment: use a loop........

Comment: `{i+1:i for i in f(n)}`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a list of variables - `[d[x] for x in l]` would create a list of the *elements* of d, which are objects, not variables. Basically, each `d[x]` doesn't resolve to "x'th position of d" but "object at x'th position of d". The outermost `[]` in `[d['1'], d['2']]` mean something different whether they are [left or right elements of an assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, it's a syntactical feature of the assignment statement. If you do something dynamic, it'll use different syntax, and thus not work.

If you have some function results `f()` and a list of keys `keys`, you can use `zip` to create an iterable of keys and results, and loop over them:

```
d = {}
for key, value in zip(keys, f()):
    d[key] = value
```

That is easily rewritten as a dict comprehension:

```
d = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, f())}
```

Or, in this specific case as mentioned by @JonClements, even as

```
d = dict(zip(keys, f()))
```

Comment: Or... `d = dict(zip(keys, f()))`